# Change href of dynamicly created link

Tags: jquery, replace, href, dynamically-generated, visual-composer

I have Wordpress site http://gambit.co/test with Visual Composer plugin which allows me to create pages in WYSIWYG mode. All content created by it is loaded with ajax and javascript. I have some nice media grid section but i cant assign  specific links to squares. They all are minatures connected to their images.

I tried to replace their links with jQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
$("a[href='http://gambit.co/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/600_wynajem.jpg']").attr('href', 'http://www.google.com/');

});
```

But i doesnt work as well because there is no HTML content when scripts runs. I moved the script to the bottom of the page, just before closing BODY tag but id didnt work. I tried both with .attr and .prop. What should i do?

Comment: `content is loaded with ajax and javascript;` so does it mean that its getting loaded by code you written using `$.ajax`; Or its something else?

Answer (score 0):

Try to take a look to [DOMNodeInserted](https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/MutationEvent).

In this way you can write something like:

```js
// as soon as a new anchor tag is added to the dom and
// the href value of this element is......
$(document).on('DOMNodeInserted', 'a[href="http://gambit.co/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/600_wynajem.jpg"]', function(e) {
  this.href = 'http://www.google.com/';
  
  this.textContent = 'http://www.google.com/';
});


$(function () {
  $('#btn').on('click', function(e) {
    $('body').append('<a href="http://gambit.co/test/wp-content/uploads/2016/07/600_wynajem.jpg">My sample</a>');
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.1.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn">Add link</button>
```